# GPU Workload with Composer 2 and GKE Autopilot?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

we have the latest Version of Composer 2 :
composer-2.0.28-airflow-2.3.3

Our GKE Version is:
1.22.12-gke.2300

We want to deploy GPU Workloads within Composer 2.

We tried as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/autopilot-gpus)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-gpu-pod
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator: nvidia-tesla-t4
  containers:
  - name: my-gpu-container
    image: nvidia/cuda:11.0.3-runtime-ubuntu20.04
    command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "--"]
    args: ["while true; do sleep 600; done;"]
    resources:
      limits:
        nvidia.com/gpu: 1
```

but it seems the examples don't work for us.

Error message is:
`Autopilot doesn't support GPUs yet.`

The documentation says:
"Ensure that you have a GKE Autopilot cluster running GKE version 1.24.2-gke.1800 or later."

Does this mean that you can't yet use GPU workloads with the current version of composer 2?

Or are we meant to go the way with GKECreateClusterOperator and setting up separate special GPU nodepool?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: With Composer 2, you'll need to wait until it adds support for 1.24.2-gke.1800 or later to use GPUs.  Of course you could manually upgrade the underlying Autopilot cluster to this version and give it a go.

Comment: @GariSingh I have composer-2.1.7-airflow-2.4.3 installed with GKE autopiolt version 1.24.9-gke.3200 . When I attempt to provision a GPU on Airflow, I get the error:

`denied by autopilot-composer-limitations]\":[\"Container 'base' specifies GPU resources. 
Cloud Composer 2 does not support creating workloads with GPUs.`

So it doesn't appear to be just an Autopilot version issue. Rather it is currently explicitly blocked?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/composer-versioning-overview

It says `Cluster nodes with GPUs=No`. Perhaps it is not supported due to policy

Answer (score 0):

In the "Before You Begin" section on the [Autopilot GPU docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/autopilot-gpus#before_you_begin):

> Ensure that you have a GKE Autopilot cluster running GKE version 1.24.2-gke.1800 or later.

For me that meant creating the cluster using the `--release-channel=rapid` flag. I ran into an issue trying to upgrade the cluster in place and just decided to chuck it, but there is probably [a path to upgrade them in place](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades-autopilot)

Comment: looks like feature request has been made. https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/235862372?pli=1

Comment: I believe at this point, autopilot supports GPUs on a non rapid release version, so this error should no longer be relevant.